# Tableau : find the ratio of change in sales of a product to all products in Quarter on Quarter bases

Tags: tableau-api, reporting, business-intelligence

Could you please help me to understand if the below calculation is possible in tableau?
If yes, please guide how to build this in tableau.

the sum of all Sales in Q3 is 10+30+14 = 54    Q2 is 5+7+1 = 13    Q1 is 1+2+5 = 8

[image]

Comment: Where do the numbers come from in the (13/8) and (54/13)?

Comment: @AndyTARSols sum of all Sales in 
Q3 = 10+30+14 = 54
Q2 = 5+7+1 = 13
Q1 = 1+2+5 = 8